# Applications of Ergodic Theory to Functional Equations

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, ergodic-theory

It is well known that Ergodic Theory has many various applications to different areas of Mathematics, such as : Number Theory, Probability Theory and Functional Equations.

I would like to enquire where the applications of Ergodic Theory to Functional Equations can be found.